# Ubuntu上のVimでクリップボードにコピーしたものが貼り付けできない

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim

Virtualbox上のUbuntuのvimでVisual Modeで選択後に<kbd>"</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>を押してクリップボードに選択内容をコピーしようとしているのですが、うまくコピーされません。

また、<kbd>"</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>も試してみましたがうまくいきませんでした。

`vim --version`を確認したところ`+clipboard`と`+xterm_clipboard`となっており、クリップボードとの連携は有効でした。

どうすればよいのでしょうか?

環境: 
Ubuntu 19.10
vim: 8.1 patch 1-320
Virtualbox: 6.0.12

Comment: 「うまくコピーされない」はコピーの時点で何かしら失敗しているということでしょうか？ / また、貼り付け先は同じVimの画面内ですか？それとも別のアプリでしょうか。